# system.data.oledb.oledbexception (0x80004005): could not find file

Tags: c#, image, ms-access-2007, oledb

Can someone help me with this error please? I can't figure it out. I have this error on Windows XP but not on Windows 7. What I did is i attached a photo and save it to the database (MS Access as my database). The photo appears on the picture box but then after that all is a mess. Im using C#.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do check that the path point to a `mdb` in the `App_Data` folder

Not very sure  but if the database is inside the `App_Data` folder, simply use:

```
"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|StaffingSystem_DB.mdb"
```

Comment: So its my connection string? This is my connection string:
`"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbCPS.accdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****"`

Comment: Yes its always there. I dont know why this happened.

Comment: @ViFer:- So did you try to change your connection string to this:- connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StaffingSystem_DB.mdb" ???

Answer (score 3):

Your data file is an accdb file, thus requiring the ACE provider instead of the JET provider. Use the JET provider to read mdb or xls files. The ACE provider, on the hand, can read mdb, accdb, xls, xlsx, plus other formats.

Also, it is best to specify complete path to you file in the Data Source property of your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Project properties->Publish->Application File, in the applications file window change Publish Status of something.accdb from Include(Auto) to Data File