# [OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find file

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, oledb

[OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find file, I have my database in the App_Data folder.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|storeDB.accdb";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the db exists in the above location and directory has sufficient read/write privileges to create files on the fly.

Please see the following links [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874731/system-data-oledb-oledbexception-0x80004005-could-not-find-file) [Link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1628595.aspx?OleDbException%200x80004005%20Could%20not%20find%20file)