# Can't open MDB (Access) file using WinForms C# app even though it exists

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

Using the code below:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\\MyFolder\\MyFile.mdb");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = sql;
con.Open();
recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\MyFolder\MyFile.mdb'.

This is in a WinForms application (C#). The file exists in that folder. I am running the application as an administrative user.

FYI, when I attempt to use a `System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\MyFolder\MyFile.mdb")`, it returns false, stating that the file does not exist. I can see the mdb in this very folder, though.

Comment: Is your connection string right? https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2000/

Comment: I changed to OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\MyFolder\\MyFile.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;"); and still get the same error.

Comment: please, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18874825/2099835

Comment: is it really .mdb? or .accdb?

Comment: Its mdb. I checked that other link previously. Even if I put the mdb into a local folder like that link suggests, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was occurring because of my SQL syntax that was hitting the Access DB.

If you specify a dot syntax (IE: SELECT * FROM [schemaname].[tablename]), the OLEDB driver will assume that the [schemaname] is the MDB file name, and will replace the file name/location specified in the connection string file with that.

My schema name happened to be the exact same name as the file name, so it was trying to find the MDB file in the wrong location.

All I had to do to fix the issue was to change my query from **SELECT * FROM [schemaname].[tablename]** to **SELECT * FROM [tablename]** and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This connection string should work:

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyFolder\MyFile.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=");

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. It still says it cannot find the mdb file even though I can see it in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Might be it is looking for the file from ur application location for an example /bin/Debug debug your connection object to see Datasource path it will giv u a hint on the issue

Comment: I've debugged to check the path and the connection is properly set

Comment: What is the OS is it 64bit or 32 bit check the driver your using problem could happen due to two reasons first app is looking file in wrong location though filepath seems correct and second driver your using cannot identify your mdb file since first case is ok it should be the driver all the coding seems correct to me

Comment: Thanks, that was closest to what the actual issue was. The path was wrong which I have explained in my answer

Comment: Glad that you figure it out!